# Celery: one worker process blocks execution of other worker processes? Shared what?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I experience a strange interaction between Celery worker processes, which I assumed to be independent. Can you suggest a possible reason for this?

I have a celery worker with multiple worker processes:

```
 PPID  PID
 5892  5919   \_ /bin/bash -c sleep 10 && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput; python manage.py migrate --noinput; python manage.py initservice; celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 5919  6168        \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 6168  6180           \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 6168  6185           \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 6168  6186           \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 6168  6187           \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 6168  6188           \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -B -A workflows --workdir=/srv/workflows -l info --autoscale=2,30 -n UNIVERSE_NODE -Q workflows worker
 ...   ...
```

Sometimes, one of the worker processes gets stuck and ... somehow it blocks all the other worker processes. When this process stops, other worker processes resume execution.

By design, there should be no shared state between worker processes, except for the worker (parent with PID 6168) and message queue + result backend. But somehow, there is some.

Can you suggest possible reasons for such a deadlock?

I'm using latest Celery 3.1, RabbitMQ as a message queue and MongoDB as results backend, default early ack and (obviously, multiprocessing mode of concurrency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason of this behavior: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#caveats. For long-running processes prefetch policy might make one process block others.

To prevent this, use `-Ofair` flag:

`$ celery -A proj worker -l info -Ofair`